# Inserting non-const pair into `std::unordered_map` is slower than const pair

Tags: c++, unordered-map, rvalue-reference

I have some code like these (from cppcon), when inserting a non-const pair into a `unordered_map`, the performance is very different to inserting with a const one.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct StopWatch {
  StopWatch() : clk{std::chrono::system_clock::now()} {}
  ~StopWatch() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = now - clk;
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count() << "ms"
         << endl;
  }
  decltype(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) clk;
};
void Benchmark_Slow(int iters) {
  std::unordered_map<string, int> m;
  std::pair<const string, int> p = {};
  while (iters--)
    m.insert(p);
}
void Benchmark_Fast(int iters) {
  std::unordered_map<string, int> m;
  const std::pair<const string, int> p = {};
  while (iters--)
    m.insert(p);
}
int main(void) {
  {
    StopWatch sw;
    Benchmark_Fast(1000000);
  }
  {
    StopWatch sw;
    Benchmark_Slow(1000000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A online demo: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/s63McEWWj)

```sh
128247ms
392454ms
```

It seems that the `const` qualifier let the compiler to choose the `unordered_map::insert(const value_type&)` overload instead of the `unordered_map::insert( P&& value )`.
[cppreference: unordered_map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)

But I think that a forwarding templated universal reference `insert(P&& value)` would be the same as an `insert` with const lvalue reference, an identical copy operation.

But the emplace one(with non-const pair) runs much slower than insert one(with const pair).

Am I missing something here ? Or if this is something has a keyword to be searched on the google, I didn't find something answers that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all add `-O2` to the compiler options. Benchmarking C++ code without optimizations enabled is completely pointless. (It doesn't seem to resolve the discrepancy though.)

Comment: @user17732522 yes it make sense , just try it out the result seems to be same.

Comment: if it helps, with a map<int, int> it does not happen.

Comment: The difference seems to depend on some libstdc++-specific detail, see https://godbolt.org/z/W4qYj7GMj. If I remember correctly libstdc++ uses explicit template instantiation for `std::string` into libstdc++.so, so some member functions will not be available for inlining. That may be the difference.

Comment: @user17732522 I am sorry for mis-describe that the rvalue insert is actually universal reference templated clearly.

Comment: @Federico thankyou it helps, I will do more investigation

Comment: @Pan Ah, I misread the overload as well. But I don't think it should make any difference which of the two are chosen. In the end they always cause construction via copy-constructor of the pair, since `p` is a lvalue in both `m.insert(p);`. There seems to be some specific optimization the compiler makes based on `p` not being able to change in the loop if it is marked `const` which it can't do without `const` because it lacks some information (presumably for the reason I mentioned earlier).

Comment: @user17732522 a good direction, I would take a look into it, thankyou.

Comment: Results with quickbench: [libstdc++](https://quick-bench.com/q/e4W5UPncNQU7_-t_KG3cX5mbdug) (different time) / [libc++](https://quick-bench.com/q/G_hzliUhR99qt-8JpF-E6UmXZAY) (equivalent time, same assembly).

Comment: Using `emplace` instead of `insert` runs in the same amount of time as the non-const version ([quickbench link](https://quick-bench.com/q/1WxbUIzLeVXr9dQZzxlaXWhx9us)).

Comment: I looked at the both overloads in libstdc++ installed on my machine and the `insert(const value_type &)` overload forwards to an `insert` method of some base class, while the `insert(P &&)` overload forwards to an `emplace` method. This would explain the execution time of using `emplace` from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I do found a possible explanation.
from [emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) it describe that if insertion fails, the constructed element would be destroyed immediately.
I follow the assembly code compiled with libstd++ of `unordered_map::emplace` (which accept templated argument and do `std::forward`) and `unordered_map::insert` [link](https://quick-bench.com/q/e4W5UPncNQU7_-t_KG3cX5mbdug) provided by @Jarod42, I the emplace one always allocate a new `hash_node` before it check if the key already in the map, because it's templated and it didn't know the argument type (maybe it only know it's `is_convertible_to`), so it do the construction before examine the key. The one in libc++ seems recognize the type is a const reference thus do the same as the insert one, copy construct occurs only if the key is not exsist.
When I modified the code with different key to be inserted, the difference gone away. [quick C++ benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/q2tpqGVzWAyejh8dKvsSVy5O9pI)

I don't know did I miss something else. I' m sorry for this trivial problem was posted.